# How do I allocate an NSObject onto its own virtual memory page in iOS?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, allocation, virtual-memory

I want to allocate an `NSObject` onto its own virtual memory page. Is this possible? It seems trivial if we could still use `NSZone`s, but they are deprecated. I tried using `NSZoneFromPointer`, but it always returned `nil`. According to [Tips for Allocating Memory](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/conceptual/managingmemory/articles/MemoryAlloc.html):

> For large memory allocations, where large is anything more than a few
>   virtual memory pages, malloc automatically uses the vm_allocate
>   routine to obtain the requested memory.

Thus, it seems like I should be able to just make my object as large as a few pages thusly:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
int[40960]; // 4096 is the default page size, so this is 10 pages.
}

@implementation MyObject
@end
```

I realize this is a hack, but would it work consistently? Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: How does making an object take up several pages relate to putting it on a specific page? Is it that you want it on its own page and you don't care which, or do you want it on a specific page that you choose?

Comment: Edited. Thanks for pointing out the poor wording @LoyalTingley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [twitter](https://twitter.com/GeekAndDad/status/389841298221699072):

> objc_constructInstance(…) might let you do what you want...

From `<objc/runtime.h>`:

```
/** 
 * Creates an instance of a class at the specific location provided.
 * 
 * @param cls The class that you wish to allocate an instance of.
 * @param bytes The location at which to allocate an instance of \e cls.
 *  Must point to at least \c class_getInstanceSize(cls) bytes of well-aligned,
 *  zero-filled memory.
 *
 * @return \e bytes on success, \c nil otherwise. (For example, \e cls or \e bytes
 *  might be \c nil)
 *
 * @see class_createInstance
 */
OBJC_EXPORT id objc_constructInstance(Class cls, void *bytes) 
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_3_0)
    OBJC_ARC_UNAVAILABLE;
```

It looks like `objc_constructInstance` is the answer.

Comment: Glad that answer pointed you in the right direction. So you can catch the exception on access like you were hoping to? Evil but neat. :)

Comment: I create the object in the page, then convert the page to read-only and trigger an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, on an expected address, but recovering from it doesn't look promising. Still, it's an interesting exercise.

Comment: If you want the rep for this answer, feel free to copy-paste it, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Nice. I was thinking of suggesting vm_allocate, bzero, and object_setClass. This seems to be the proper replacement for those last two.

Comment: thanks. No big deal.  I was establishing my "rep" 20 years before SO was created :)

Answer (score -2):

I don't think as a user-level application you are supposed to have any control over virtual memory assignments. Apps in iOS are in a sandbox.

Comment: You can call vm_allocate in an iOS app just fine. I'm not sure that app sandboxing has anything to do with it. The same problem exists on OSX with the modern Objective-C runtime.